# Angular seed gets stuck at "Loading..." after adding router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

In a new Angular seed application (`ng new`), the application gets stuck at "Loading..." as soon as I add this to app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I did try injecting `Router`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router) { }
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

and things got even weirder. As long as I have the `router-outlet` tag it's still stuck at "Loading...". As soon as I remove that (but `Router` is still being injected), I get a blank screen (i.e., not even "Loading...").

app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm getting four browser errors:

[image]

Comment: Will you please share your app.module.ts file.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: You need to import `RouterModule`.

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
....
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
```

You need to add router module inside your `app.module.ts` file

Comment: I'm getting a blank page. It is app.component because any plain text/html is shown. But no data binding is happening (e.g., <h1>{{title}}</h1> shows empty)

Comment: Post your component file also.

Comment: Done, and more added

Comment: Please read basics about router, how to define routes, next step is to provide routing path.

Comment: Yes I found my mistake. Thanks